# sqlalchemy: Same Base for different tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metadata, software-design, radix

I have different tables, that I declare in a very standard way, but with a global Base:

**GlobalData.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

init()
engine= ...
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

**TableA.py**

```
import globaldata as gd
TableA(gd.Base)
...
```

**TableB.py**

```
import globaldata as gd
TableB(gd.Base)
...
```

Problem: 
If I import TableA or to TableB more than once in other files, the tables will be added more than once in the metadata. Then this created conflict when I try any action on one of those tables.

---

### EDIT

The issue I receive, when I try to access a table is :

> Multiple classes found for path "RolloutPermission" in the registry of
>   this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.

I assume this is a design issue, however, I don't see what is wrong with mine. Any input is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I also kind of did the same as you did, sort of. I only declare the base and import it everywhere, like you do, but without this code

```
init()   

engine=Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I import my base then in an env file from alembic and generate migrations. If you're going to work with a slightly more complex I highly recommand migration files :).

The problem might indeed be that you basically call create_all on every import.
Look into alembic, get rid of the few lines I wrote above and you'll have working code :)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help that much. You don't explain how you prevent multiple paths for the same Base